# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar el usuario root en un servidor web?

Tags: linux, servidor

Alguien sabe cómo puedo quitar el usuario `root` en un servidor web linux Debian o Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

El usuario `root` no es algo que quieras eliminar, lo que normalmente se quiere es inhabilitar el acceso `SSH` para el usuario `root`.

Antes de seguir debes tener en cuenta que deberás haber creado otro usuario y que puedas conectarte con él al servidor por medio de `SSH`.

Por ejemplo, vamos a crear un usuario llamado `admin` para que te puedas loguear con él en lugar de tener que usar el `root`.

```
adduser admin
gpasswd -a admin sudo
```

Ahora que ya tienes el usuario creado se recomienda que le actives el acceso `SSH`a ese nuevo usuario (a menos que tengas otra forma de acceder, por ejemplo si tienes acceso físico al servidor), para ello deberás copiar tu llave `SSH` pública (voy a asumir que ya tienes generadas tus llaves `SSH`.

Este paso deberás ejecutarlo en tu máquina local y NO en el servidor.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Eso te generará una cadena de texto bastante larga (tu llave SSH). Copiala al portapapeles.

Ahora sí, regresamos al servidor, logueado aún como `root` y ejecutas:

```
su - admin
```

Esto te pasará al usuario `admin` y te localizará en el `home` de dicho usuario. Ahora crea una carpeta llamada `.ssh` y restringe los permisos:

```
mkdir .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
```

Luego abre el siguiente archivo:

```
nano .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Pega en este archivo la llave `SSH` que copiaste antes.

Luego restringe los permisos:

```
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Regresa al usuario `root`:

```
exit
```

Ahora sí, habiendo creado y probado el nuevo usuario, vamos a desactivar el acceso al usuario `root`. Para ello debes editar el archivo `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, por ejemplo, si usas `nano`como editor podrías hacerlo así:

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Luego encontrarás una línea que dice:

```
#PermitRootLogin yes
```

Sustitúyela por esta:

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

Asegúrate que puedes conectarte con otro usuario a tu servidor antes de reiniciar el servicio `sshd` para evitar quedarte sin poder entrar a tu servidor.

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

o bien, si eso no te funciona puede probar con:

```
service ssh restart
```

Y listo, ya puedes loguearte al servidor con tu nuevo usuario `admin` pero ya no con el usuario `root`.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es que no haya acceso al usuario `root` y dejar el sistema tal como estaba antes de habilitar la cuenta de root hay que eliminar su password:

```
sudo gedit /etc/passwd
```

Busca la línea:

```
root:X:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Borra la X y guarda.

Si quieres volver a habilitarla:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Información obtenida de los [foros de Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu-es.org/node/38781).